# $_POST not submitting the form, array prints as array()

Tags: php, arrays, forms, .htaccess, post

Below is the form I'm using to submit a new wheel into a DB on my local XAMPP server, problem is the post method doesn't work, I had problems with a modal which was sorted by using $_GET instead. I've changed a few `php.ini` settings but have changed them back was, max_upload and another one, I've read about them in other questions but they don't seem to solve the issue.

When I use the submit form below the array printed is just `Array()`, doesn't even have a single value, this should prompt my error check to print an error at the least.

```
<!-- wheels form -->
<div class="text-center">
    <form class="form-inline" action="wheels.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="wheelName">Add a new wheel:</label>
            <input name="wheelName" type="text" id="wheelName" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['wheelName']))?$_POST['wheelName']:''); ?> "><!-- shorthand if/else-->
            <label for="code">Stockcode</label>
            <input name="code" type="text" id="code" class="form-control" value="<?=((isset($_POST['code']))?$_POST['code']:''); ?> "><!-- shorthand if/else-->
            <input type="submit" name="add_submit" value="add wheel" class="btn btn-success">
        </div>
    </form>
</div><hr>
```

Standard php sql input and checks, the information is being pulled correctly as I have it displaying in a table further on my page.But the $_POST variable appears to be completely empty, has someone had this problem and managed to sort it? I'm assuming its to do with my php setup or `.htaccess` as someone else had an issue with.

```
<?php
require_once '../core/init.php';
include 'includes/header.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';

// Get wheels from DB
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wheels ORDER BY part_no";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$errors = array();

// edit wheel
if(isset($_GET['edit']) && !empty(['edit'])) {
    $edit_id = (int)$_GET['edit'];
    $edit_id = sanitize('edit_id');
    //$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE recid = '$edit_id'";
    //$edit_result = $db->query($sql2);
    //$eWheel = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_result);
}

// Delete wheel
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty(['delete'])) {
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
    $delete_id = sanitize($delete_id);
    //$sql = "DELETE FROM wheels WHERE recid = '$delete_id'";
    //$db->query($sql);
    //header('Location: wheels.php');
}

// If add wheel form submitted
if(isset($_POST['add_submit'])) {
    $wheel = sanitize($_POST['wheelName']);
    $stockCode = sanitize($_POST['stockCode']);

    // check if wheel is blank
    if($_POST['wheelName'] == '') {
        $errors[] .= 'Must enter wheel';
    }

    // if wheel exists in db
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE stockcode = '$stockCode'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($count > 0) {
        $errors[] .= 'that wheel already exists.';
    }

    // display errors
    if(!empty($errors)) {
        echo displayErrors($errors);
    } else {
        //Add wheels to DB // incomplete unsure if feature needed at this stage.
        // $sql = "INSERT INTO wheels (wheelName, stockCode, ID ETC ETC VALUES Etc ETC
        // $db->query($sql);
        // header ('location : wheels.php ');

    }
}

var_dump($_POST);
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
?>
```

Here is the log

```
::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:32 +1200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:32 +1200] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6904 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:32 +1200] "GET /dashboard/stylesheets/normalize.css HTTP/1.1" 200 6876 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:32 +1200] "GET /dashboard/stylesheets/all.css HTTP/1.1" 200 481308 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:32 +1200] "GET /dashboard/javascripts/modernizr.js HTTP/1.1" 200 51365 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:33 +1200] "GET /dashboard/javascripts/all.js HTTP/1.1" 200 189003 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:33 +1200] "GET /dashboard/images/xampp-logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 5427 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:33 +1200] "GET /dashboard/images/bitnami-xampp.png HTTP/1.1" 200 22133 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:33 +1200] "GET /dashboard/images/fastly-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1770 "http://localhost/dashboard/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [23/Apr/2016:14:12:33 +1200] "GET /dashboard/images/social-icons.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3361 "http://localhost/dashboard/stylesheets/all.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
```

[image]

Comment: Open Developer Tools and go to the Network tab to see if the form fields are being sent.

Comment: Are you using any Javascript to process the form before submitting?

Comment: Also check the DOM, make sure the inputs are really inside the `<form>`. If there's invalid HTML, that could move things around.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I've checked the network before and nothing is being sent, also no Javascript and the <form> is correct.

Comment: Got a link to the site we can look at?

Comment: Its just on my localhost, so not live, I might boot up my other computer and see if it works, or setup a vm and try it.

Comment: i just created a file with that html code, and it posts the information just fine.  it's not the html,    but are you sure your PHP file is named "wheels.php"??  because that's where you're actually sending the POST

Comment: @jcode you said there's a <?php tag at the top of this page, is there a ?> closing tag before your next <?php open tag, that is not shown here? If not, this can't work, '<?php' within php will just throw an error. please post the complete code.

Comment: Yes php has opening and closing tag, Ive moved the var_dump into the main php tags with the sql. I believe its an error with my computer php.

Comment: try echoing 'file_get_contents("php://input")' if nothing is there than, it's most likely not php,

Comment: it outputs array(0) { } wheelName=+&code=+&add_submit=add+wheel

Comment: Updated the full php area

Comment: array(0) { } wheelName=+&code=+&add_submit=add+wheel, means your data is being sent to the server but not as POST, it will not be in the php $_POST variable array. Do you have access to your server access log?

Comment: Yes I do, I've added in the log from the most recent attempt to post.

Comment: Do you have php short tags enabled?

Comment: I have enabled it now in the php.ini, still doesn't work.

Comment: add an enctype 'enctype='multipart/form-data' to your form.

Comment: @gmfm Why do you think that's not as POST? The normal format for POST data is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the same format as URL query strings.

Comment: Correct, but I have had this problem with ajax post submissions before, and that was the solution that worked. I'm not sure why this would happen, but if you add the enctype and the submission works, you've narrowed your error down.

Comment: array(0) { } ------WebKitFormBoundarynSSREIcV8Zti46vE Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wheel" ------WebKitFormBoundarynSSREIcV8Zti46vE Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code" ------WebKitFormBoundarynSSREIcV8Zti46vE Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add_submit" add wheel ------WebKitFormBoundarynSSREIcV8Zti46vE--

Comment: Is the response, No idea, like I said third different project POST hasn't worked on. Just going to assume I can't test it on this machine

Comment: You should separate getting SQL data from submitting the form. Remove all the PHP code and just call `print_r($_POST)` to make sure that the form is posted. Then leave just the code that deals with database, and make sure that db results are correct.

Answer (score 0):

well, i think you should place the `<?php`  line at the very top of the file... before the "Get wheels from DB" comment

And instead of `print_r($_POST);`  use `var_dump($_POST);`

also, in the section "if wheel exists in db"  your sql query  is never using the `$stockCode`  variable,   you're missing the `$` , it should be `$sql = "SELECT * FROM wheels WHERE stockcode = '$stockCode'";`

And drop the point before the equal sign for the errors. thats for Strings, and as an array `$errors[] = 'that wheel already exists.';`  should work fine

Comment: None of this explains why the form is submitting nothing.

Comment: ummm,  i think it's getting "nothing" because all the PHP code is just 'print_r ($_POST);'   and it prints   "array()"    so it means that it is getting an array in $_POST,    if he uses var_dump  he'll see everything he's getting from the form...    but the rest of the code is not being considered as PHP so it does nothing....

Comment: Sorry there is the opening php at the top of the page, just figured it wasn't needed.

Comment: Both `print_r` and `var_dump` show the contents of the array, they just do it in different formats.

Comment: var_dump just posts array(0) { }

Comment: The problem is the form is failing to pass the information, as this is now the third time I've attempted to use post on my computer and it fails to do anything I'm convinced its a problem with the php.ini file or another setting in Xampp.

Comment: ok,  are you sure your php file is called "wheels.php"???   and in your html the input for the code is named just "code"   and in your PHP you're expecting   "stockCode", this is not the problem of not getting the POST, but once you get it, it would be another problem xD

Comment: @Jcode You said the Network tab shows that nothing is being sent. So the php.ini is irrelevant, the problem is in the HTML.